How to accept cookies popup with Selenium IDE only if popup is being shown
I'm running a Selenium IDE .js test that goes to a website and perform a login and some more button clicks after that. Sometimes the website is showing the cookies policy popup and sometimes not so I would like my check to pass no matter what.
I managed to click the "Enable all" button with the script below but I would like the whole test suite to continue in case the cookie popup is now shown when running the test. The following code will just break the whole test by waiting to the "Enable all" buton that will never show up sometimes.
      .then(function () {
        return (
          logger.log(8, "Click By.xpath('//<div>[text()=Enable all]')", "Untitled"),
          $browser
            .waitForAndFindElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Enable all']"), DefaultTimeout)
            .then((e) => (e.click(), Promise.resolve(!0)))
        );
      })

